# Cambiar valores de un response

Tags: angular, typescript

buen día.

Estoy trabajando sobre una función donde la cual hace una consulta cada 30 segundos para obtención de un Token. Intente cambiarlo con un `map` y si hace el remplazo que quiero pero al momento de revisar el request, no cambia el valor.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "transactionID": "74792a7c-e36e-4777-9c5c-54c18e3c8b00",
        "time": "2024-01-17T16:58:07-07:00",
        "time_elapsed": "1.638491ms"
    },
    "data": {
        "exp": "Wed, 17 Jan 2024 17:12:20 MST",
        "expText": "14m12.245246605s",
        "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBJZCI6IiIsImVtYWlsIjoiai5vcy5lLnN3YWxrZXIuakBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ1c2VyIjoiOTAyNTc2OTIiLCJ1c2VyVHlwZSI6IjAiLCJsb2dpblR5cGUiOjEwLCJkZXZpY2VJZCI6IiIsInBhaXMiOiJtZXgiLCJleHRlcm5vIjpmYWxzZSwiaXBPcmlnZW4iOiIxMC41OS4zMy4yMTMiLCJEYXRhIjpudWxsLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2NvcHBlbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE3MDU1MzY3ODcsImp0aSI6IjE3MDU1MzU4NDAtai5vcy5lLnN3YWxrZXIuakBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDUyMzUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vY29wcGVsLmNvbSIsIm5iZiI6MTcwNTIzNSwic3ViIjoiai5vcy5lLnN3YWxrZXIuakBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.xJa3K4yofAAAttsQ_BIwylKj7avGWUHa800gPwjYVzM",
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Imoub3MuZS5zd2Fsa2VyLmpAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlciI6IjkwMjU3NjkyIiwidXNlclR5cGUiOiIwIiwibG9naW5UeXBlIjoxMCwicGFpcyI6Im1leCIsImlwT3JpZ2VuIjoiMTAuNTkuMzMuMjEzIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jb3BwZWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNzA1NTM2NzQwLCJqdGkiOiIxNzA1NTM1ODQwLWoub3MuZS5zd2Fsa2VyLmpAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNzA1MjM1LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2NvcHBlbC5jb20iLCJuYmYiOjE3MDUyMzUsInN1YiI6Imoub3MuZS5zd2Fsa2VyLmpAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.ngx2By5b17A8lZZ_z5W-VhZGYjbVisBoRD9d6k4HKaI"
    }
}
```

Este es el json que me devuelve pero lo quiero es que en el objeto de data, el valor del `refresh_token`, lo reemplace por el que esta en el valor de `token`.

```
/**
   * Verificación de token vigente, cada 30 segundos.
   */
  public polling(): void {
    interval(POLLING_TIME)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.http.post<any>(API_URL + '/v2/verify', null)),
        map((response) => {
          const refresh_token = response.data.refresh_token;
          response.data.token = refresh_token;
          console.log(refresh_token);
          return response;
        }),
        takeUntil(this.destructionSubject$.asObservable())
      )
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          // TODO: Añadir control de excepciones
        },
        () => this.modalCierreSesion()
      );
  }
```